# Brightness Control : Asus X453MA : Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, brightness, backlight

I cannot adjust the screen brightness using the `Fn` keys. I have scoured the net to find a solution and so far this is what I have :

- I've tried creating/editing `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` as mentioned in many tutorials but this has had no effect
- I've tried to edit the /etc/default/grub file many different ways. So far nothing has worked. Only progress: changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="` has enabled the popup notification when the `Fn` keys are used but the actual screen brightness hasn't changed.
- `acpi_listen` also proves the keys are registering correctly
- I'm able to adjust the brightness through the terminal by using `xbacklight`
- `$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
  acpi_video0  intel_backlight`
- Probing the files in both of these folders I have understood that using the Fn keys alters the value of `.../acpi_video0/brightness`
- Using `xbacklight` alters the value of `.../intel_backlight/brightness`

Seems like the simplest solution would be to make the `Fn` alter the same file as `xbacklight` does but I have no clue how to do this.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keyboard shortcuts to run `xbacklight` commands with the options to reproduce <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> feature keys on actual keyboard, without using <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

To increase brightness by 10%: `xbacklight -inc 10`

To decrease brightness by 10%: `xbacklight -dec 10`

First, run the suggested commands above in the terminal. After you have confirmed these commands work on your machine, then you can proceed to add keyboard shortcuts for these commands.

In Xubuntu 14.04, the steps to add keyboard shortcut as follows.

1. Go to **Settings Manager - Hardware > Keyboard**
2. Select **Applications Shortcuts** and click **Add**.
3. In the first dialog window, enter the suggested command (one at a time) and click **OK**.
4. In the next dialog window, press keyboard keys of your choice to be assigned for the command.

Once you have pressed keyboard keys of your choice, the dialog window will close automatically and the new keyboard shortcut will be registered. Repeat the steps for the other command.

Do not use <kbd>Fn</kbd> key because that will not work. Suggested keyboard shortcuts as follows.

To increase brightness: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

To decrease brightness: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

For Asus laptops, which may vary by model, <kbd>F5</kbd> key has icon for dimming the screen and <kbd>F6</kbd> key has icon for brightening the screen. Therefore, these keys are better reused with one of modifier keys (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>) to give similar experience to adjust the brightness. Although, this is a matter of preference.